# How to make a character controller in unity without coding

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there  an option to make a character controller in unity without coding? Can I do it using components only?

Comment: Why without coding? what pupose do you ?

Answer (score 2):

Components only? You'll probably need to get a asset store asset, or use bolt for easy visual scripting.
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/visual-scripting/bolt-163802

Of course, the best way of making one is learning c# and watching tutorials until you can make a character controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid writing code entirely, then it will be very difficult.

However, if you prefer a more visual style of doing logic, then perhaps you should look into [Unity's Visual Scripting solution](https://unity.com/features/unity-visual-scripting).
This can replace a good part of writing code, but you will have to write scripts for complex behaviors.

If it is just the character controller you wish to avoid writing, then perhaps you want to look at Unity's default starter assets for a [third person](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/starter-assets-third-person-character-controller-196526) and a [first person character controller](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/starter-assets-first-person-character-controller-196525).

If you are referring to the component [CharacterController](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html), then it can help in setting up a basic controller but it has several issues when trying to do more complex movements. See [rigidbody vs character controller](https://medium.com/ironequal/unity-character-controller-vs-rigidbody-a1e243591483).

I would recommend getting comfortable with coding if you are to pursue making a game by yourself.